# How do I parse nested json objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to load a JSON file to parse the contents nested in the root object. Currently I have the JSON file open and loaded as such:

```
with open(outputFile.name) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

For the sake of the question here is an example of what the contents of the JSON file are like:

```
{
"rootObject" : 
{
    "person" : 
    {
        "address" : "some place ave. 123",
        "age" : 47,
        "name" : "Joe"
        
    },
    "kids" : 
    [
        
        {
            "age" : 20,
            "name" : "Joey",
            "studySubject":"math"
        },
        
        {
            "age" : 16,
            "name" : "Josephine",
            "studySubject":"chemistry"
        }
       
    ],
    "parents" : 
    {
        "father" : "Joseph",
        "mother" : "Joette"
    }
```

How do I access the nested objects in "rootObject", such as "person", "kids" and its contents, and  "parents"?

Comment: `data['rootObject']['person']['name']`  and  `for kid in data['rootObject']['kids']:`

Comment: Once `json.load` returns a Python value, the fact that you started with JSON isn't really relevant anymore. `data` isn't JSON; it's just a Python `dict`.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much. Makes much more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Below code using recursive function can **extract values using specific key** in a nested dictionary or 'lists of dictionaries':

```
data = {
"rootObject" : 
{
    "person" : 
    {
        "address" : "some place ave. 123",
        "age" : 47,
        "name" : "Joe"
        
    },
    "kids" : 
    [
        
        {
            "age" : 20,
            "name" : "Joey",
            "studySubject":"math"
        },
        
        {
            "age" : 16,
            "name" : "Josephine",
            "studySubject":"chemistry"
        }
       
    ],
    "parents" : 
    {
        "father" : "Joseph",
        "mother" : "Joette"
    }
}}

def get_vals(nested, key):
    result = []
    if isinstance(nested, list) and nested != []:   #non-empty list
        for lis in nested:
            result.extend(get_vals(lis, key))
    elif isinstance(nested, dict) and nested != {}:   #non-empty dict
        for val in nested.values():
            if isinstance(val, (list, dict)):   #(list or dict) in dict
                result.extend(get_vals(val, key))
        if key in nested.keys():   #key found in dict
            result.append(nested[key])
    return result

get_vals(data, 'person')
```

Output

```
[{'address': 'some place ave. 123', 'age': 47, 'name': 'Joe'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

The code for loading the `JSON object` should look like this:

```
from json import loads, load

with open("file.json") as file:
    var = loads(load(file))
    # loads() transforms the string in a python dict object
```

Comment: I’m sure your code is wrong and the OP is correct in just using ‘load()’

Comment: Unless `load(file)` returns a JSON string, this is just an error.

Comment: `load(f)` itself is little more than a wrapper around `loads(f.read())`.